# PostSharp and C++/Cli

Tags: .net, c++-cli, postsharp, aop

I am currently evaluating the PostSharp framework for AOP. The solution I would be using it for consists of a C# library and a C++/CLI library. The C++/CLI library offers some specialized implementations of interfaces in the C# library.

I added PostSharp and the [Undo/Redo demo from the PostSharp site](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/undoredo) to the solution. NuGet tells me that both projects use the PostSharp-NuGet package.

All the properties used in C# code work flawlessly. I can track every change, undo and redo it as expected.

In the C++/CLI code however, nothing happens. All the changes are ignored. It seems the aspect is never injected, or gets ignored somehow. However, the code does compile with the custom attribute set:

```
using namespace PostSharp::Extensibility;
using namespace UndoDemo;

public ref class A
{
    [Undoable(AttributeInheritance = MulticastInheritance::Multicast)]
    virtual property int N;
};
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 and PostSharp 3.0.33.

Is PostSharp known not to work with C++/CLI? Or are there any special steps one has to take in order to get PostSharp to work with mixed-mode classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented, it only supports c# and VB.NET: [postSharp 3.0 Ducumentaion](http://www.postsharp.net/downloads/documentation/PostSharp-3.0.pdf)

Also attributes does not modify or change the code in any circumstance... So applying attributes has no effect unil there is no one who is chcking for this attributes... Also compilation is not a problem...

You might try to use PostSharp with safe or pure c++/CLI code [see /clr compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx) . But in this cas it normally makes no sence to use C++/CLI...